# use svg images withing graphviz

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot

I can use png images for nodes in graphviz and output a svg grap.
To do this I use for exemple :

```
n [shape=none, label="", image="image.png"];
```

But it doesn't seem to work with a svg image.

Is this possible ?
I am using Graphviz 2.38 Stable Release.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed.  I'm running 2.40.1 and I can use an SVG image and still output SVG.

Comment: @tk421 no luck for Windows users then, if this feature is indeed expected not to work with  2.38 .

Comment: If you wish to use graphviz above 2.38 the easiest I have found is to download the code and compile it yourself. There is a step to getting the requirements https://graphviz.gitlab.io/doc/winbuild.html. If you are using Visual studio, retarget each project to the WIN SDK you have installed in your machine.